# Is keeping dolls of animals haram?

Tags: halal-haram, shirk

There are two dolls of elephants made of clay just for the beautification of the house. Is it permissible in Islam?

Answer (score -1):

For beauty of house that is not permissible. Dolls are permissible only for little girls.

Comment: Please consider taking some time to elaborate your answer and read [answer].